# Implement a custom theme Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme

I am not able to implement a custom theme in Magento 2 (on mac os x) 
can you provide me with information please?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: Check link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

So your operating system is not important in this case. Magento has a certain way to do things. For every aspect you will need to know the structure of Magento and how they implement it.

If you have bought or already have a theme you will just need to go add your theme to your app/design/frontend directory following your theme's instructions and then go to you admin settings and go to **content->Design->configuration**. Select the website or storefront where you want to apply it and select your theme under Default **Theme->Applied Theme**

If you want to code your own Theme you will need to create a theme under the `app/design/frontend/YourVender/YourTheme` (or adminhtml if you want to change the backend) folder.

There you will need to create a `theme.xml` in your theme directory file like this :

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>My Theme Name</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

You will also need to create a `registration.php` in your theme directory :

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

When you have done that it will inherit everything from the blank theme of Magento (you can also inherit from the luma theme by changing `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>` to `<parent>Magento/luma</parent>` in your `theme.xml`

**Adjust HTML**

Now you can referenence .phtml files from the `vendor/magento` folder in your `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme` folder and overwrite them. An example :

In your `vendor/magento/module-catalog` folder you will find a `view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` . If we want to override it we need to copy/past that fille to our `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` .

We can now adjust the html behind it and give it new classes.

As you can see they use **modules** and we use a **theme** so our filepath is a bit different. In a module you can have a `view/frontend` and a `view/adminhtml` to define to scope that you are working in. Our theme is made for `frontend` OR `adminhtml`  and we already are working with only css/js/phtml/xml so we don't need a `view` folder. This results that we do not need to define view/frontend anymore but we do need to refer to the module from magento that we want to override. Creating `themedir/Module_Name/templates/Path/fille.phtml`.

**Adjust css**

You can create css filles in your themedir/css/ folder (lets say we create an example.css) and add them to every page by creating a `themedir/Magento_Theme/default_head_blocks.xml` with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/example.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

But this is **BAD PRACTICE** . The reason why is because you will create separate css files that load in separately every time you load a page creating a slow loading website...

The right way to adjust things is with `themedir/web/css/source/_extend.less` and `themedir/web/css/source/_theme.less`. Within `_theme.less` we refer to existing classes from Magento to overwrite styles that they have. Withing `_extend.less` we refer to new styling and classes that we made.

To compile (less to css) these delete your content of the `var/cache` , `var/view_preprocessed` , `var_page_cache` and `pub/static` folders and recompile your website with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

*With this it will compile your css in the css fille of Magento itself thus not creating now files to load and resulting in an optimized website.*

**Adjusting Javascript/Jquery**

If needed i can explain this. This is a lot of explanation about requireJS and how to use it so not sure if you will need this. Ask if you need this.

**Adjusting PHP logics and moving Blocks**

So i discussed phtml and css but a big factor in making your own theme is involved about `.xml` files with `containers` and `Blocks` also.

You can find a lot of information about that here :
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

So the basic idea is that you have `.xml` files that are responsible where which .phtml file is on your page.

First of all the basic markup is like this :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<container name="content">
<block class="My/Module/Block/Class" name="block1" template='Magento_Theme::custom.phtml" />
<block class="My/Module/Block/Class2" name="block2" template='Magento_Theme::custo2.phtml" after="block1"/>
</container>
</page>
```

*You can move these around with the link that i gave you and the information on that page.*

Explanation :

```
<page> This is just a markup so Magento recognizes the Xml as a page_configuration
<container> This holds multiple Blocks. This is used to group things and to add Blocks to this container later by using <referenceContainer>
<block> Here you can define your phtml by using 'Vendor_Module::path/theme.phtml' and this reference to the template folder/path/theme.phtml.
```

You can also refer to classes in your block with the `class='vendor/module/path/class'` attribute of your `<block />`.

This class is stored in the `$block` variable in your template file . If you have a public function defined in your class you can use it in your `.phtml file` with `$block->thefunctionname()`

You can also define Blocks within Blocks and the those are called `childblocks`. These are not visible on your page unless you call for them in your parent Block with the `->getChildBlock()` or -`>getChildHtml()` functions

**Sidenote :** You can not create PHP classes within your theme folder. You will need to create a Module to refer to. Usually this is done by adding a `app/code/YourTheme/Core/` module.

**This is a lot of information , i hope this was helpful for you.
Give it a thumbs up and an 'answer' vote if you liked it.**