# How to change category layouts for specific types of products magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, category

For certain categories,  rather than an add to cart button, and price and regular stuff, I want to just say click for more details.
And for some product pages, I want to keep the informational - pictures and descriptions and other attributes - but no add to cart button, compare button etc.
All other categories and products are normal.

Is it possible to do this? What files would I customize? Is a module available for this?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to customize a theme or create one here is my explenation about it :
[Implement a custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200087/implement-a-custom-theme-magento-2)

Now if you have read that or you know that :

**vendor/magento/module_catalog** is the place to search. In those `.phtml files` (view/frontend/templates) you will find -> product/list.phtml and you can add your own logics here following my previous url. This is defined in `layout/catalog_category_view.xml`